# How to detect DB changes and write them to a screen

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I am creating an app where a user can submit an alert, and all other users should be alerted. I am trying to use the firebase realtime database for this. A basic alert looks like the image below.

[image: alert]

I have tried using `firebase.database.on`, and using the firebase events detailed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), all to no avail.

Here is a very simplified version of my code that tries to detect when a new alert is added to firebase.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class AlertScreen extends React.Component {

    user = this.props.navigation.getParam('user','error');

    alerts = []

    checkAlerts = async() => {
        await firebase.database().ref('alerts/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
            return snapshot
        })
    }

    render() {

        this.checkAlerts().then(a => {
            this.alerts.push(a)
        })

        return (
            <View>
                { this.alerts }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I would expect this to update with some output each time there was a new alert, but really it returns a `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Undefined is not an object. (Evaluating this.alerts.push()).]`. I also want to send a notification to the user when the firebase on event is triggered. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `alerts` has already been defined when you do `then(alerts...` and you then try to push to the original.  Call it something different in the promise callback.  Also, the return will take place before the promise is complete.  Make a call inside `then()` to render the changes.

Comment: Great point! Fixing that now and will update question

Comment: @Archer Not sure I understand how to fix the second part though

Comment: I don't use React so I can't help fix it, but `Render()` basically says - get the alerts, and when you've finished push them into the array, but return a view immediately.  This is the crux of async requests (AJAX & promises).

Comment: `on` doesn't return a promise.  It attaches a persistent listener.  Use `once` instead if you need a promise.

Comment: @DougStevenson if I use once though, it would not update when a new alert was added. How would I correctly use on in this situation?

Comment: Well, `on` doesn't return a promise, as it doesn't ever really finish until you tell it `off`, so you can't use it like you are now.  I don't build apps with react, so I don't know how folks normally wire things up, but you will have to handle the snapshot from within the callback.  You can't just `return` it out.